# Return value of (void*) 57600 in C

Tags: pointers, embedded, void, uart, blackfin

I am reading the source code of a `UART` peripheral and there is a function as below:

```
eResult = adi_stdio_ControlDevice (hSTDIOUART,
    ADI_STDIO_COMMAND_SET_UART_BAUD_RATE, (void *)57600);
```

This function is used to connect `UART` and number `57600` is the baudrate. What I do not understand is the meaning of `(void*)57600`.

I think this maybe a pointer to `const` and the return value of `(void*)57600` is `57600`. When we use `(void*)57600`, does it mean we are creating a pointer that points to the `57600` value?

And why we must use `(void*)57600`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. The "return value" (quoted because it's not actually being returned from a function, instead it's the result of a cast) of `(void *)57600` is simply the value `57600` being treated as (or, in other words, cast to) a void pointer.

And, while you are actually *converting* `57600` to a void pointer, it's almost certainly not being *used* as a pointer. More likely is that the prototype for `adi_stdio_ControlDevice` has a generic argument (one that can be used for many things).

Device control functions are particularly apt to do that since they are meant to be generic across a large variety of devices, so you may have to give a wide variety of types to the calls.

You'll *probably* find that, for the command to set the baud rate, it simply gets cast back to an integral value at the other end before being used, something like:

```
static int localSpeed;
static char *localString;
static double localPi;
static struct rational { int numerator; int denominator } localStruct;

bool adi_stdio_ControlDevice (HANDLE hndl, COMMAND cmd, void *generic) {
    switch (cmd) {
        case ADI_STDIO_COMMAND_SET_UART_BAUD_RATE: {
            localSpeed = (int)generic;
            break;
        }
        case ADI_COMMAND_WITH_STRING_ARG: {
            if (localString) free(localString);
            localString = strdup((char*)generic);
            break;
        }
        case ADI_COMMAND_WITH_DOUBLE_PTR_ARG: {
            localPi = *((double*)generic));
            break;
        }
        case ADI_COMMAND_WITH_STRUCT_PTR: {
            memcpy(localStruct, generic, sizeof(localStruct));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Other commands (such as the fake ones I've added) would be able to use the generic argument in a variety of ways, as integers or other pointer types for example.

---

This is actually supported by the documentation (VisualDSP++ 5.0 Device Drivers and System Services Manual for Blackfin® Processors) for that call, which states:

> `ADI_STDIO_RESULT adi_stdio_ControlDevice (`
>      `ADI_STDIO_DEVICE_HANDLE hStdioDevice,`
>      `uint32_t nCommandID,`
>      `void *const pValue`
>    `);`
>    `: : :`
>   `pValue`: Argument required for executing the command. ***Depending upon the command, different types of arguments are required.***

Comment: Thank you. So as i understanding, we have to use (void*)57600 beacause the input of adi_stdio_ControlDevice() need a void *const. Now i am wondering what is type casting actually do in C. If i write (void*) 57600, so it will change data type of 57600 from something (i do not know because it is constant) to a void pointer (4 byte with 32 bit system). Is this true ? And in the virtual memory allocation of C, there will be two memory are, one is used for const 57600 and one is used for pointer voide* 57600 ? (this seem not true).

Comment: Yes, @Lundin, it's not the best, it's just the way they chose it to allow any type of argument. From memory, the UNIX/Linux `ioctl()`is very similar.

Comment: @Thanh, `(void*)N` doesn't really create another "thing", it rather just treats `N` as if it were a void pointer. Similar to `(float) 1 / 3` which would do floating point division (to get `0.33`-ish) because you're treating the integer `1` as a float rather than an integer (`1 / 3` would truncate to zero because it's integer division).

Comment: i have read document "VisualDSP++ 5.0 Device Drivers and System Services Manual for Blackfin® Processors", there are many helpful API function, but i do not want to use API function because i could help me to actually understand about how chip works. Could you recommend me some document or example, web,...etc which program blackfin chip by register value?